# Go to dictionary key from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary tree with a long line of values:

```
dict = {"a":{"b":{"c":"Hello World!"}}}
```

And if I wish to print out "Hello World!" From inside the dictionary, I would have to do this:

```
print(dict["a"]["b"]["c"])
```

However, I wish to be able to travel through the dictionary by using a list. In theory, this is how it would work:

```
dict = {"a":{"b":{"c":"Hello World!"}}}
list = ["a", "b", "c"]
print(dict[list])
```

And python would print "Hello World!", however this doesn't seem to be how it works. Any ideas would be of great help!

Comment: Basically, you just can't do that. You would have to create your own function to apply each key to each level.

Comment: so always value is at last???

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Not much of a function to write (see my answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reduce` (which in Python 3 you need to import with `from functools import reduce`).

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a[b], key_list, my_dict)
```

Like this:

```
my_dict = {"a":{"b":{"c":"Hello World!"}}}
key_list = ["a", "b", "c"]

>>> reduce(lambda a, b: a[b], key_list, my_dict)
'Hello World!'
```

An exception will be raised if any of the keys don't exist (or if the dictionary nesting is too "shallow" so that there aren't as many dicts as keys).

Note that I renamed your variables.  It's not a good idea to use `list` and `dict` as variable names because they shadow the builtin types with those names.

Comment: The OPs tagged this as 3.x, so you'll need a `from functools import reduce`

Comment: Would it be possible to also use this to edit the dictionary? For example (in an ideal world, something like: dict[list].update(new_dict))

Comment: @Inazuma: To do that, just remove the last key so that what you get is a reference to the inner dict.  If you do `key_list = ['a', 'b']` then the result of the `reduce` will be the inner dict, which you can update or whatever you like.